# Intent does not work in switch statement

Tags: java, android

I have a switch case if signin button is pressed it should move to the next Activity. However, for some reason it does not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnAccSignup;
    private Button btnSignin;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAccSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccSignup);
        btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignin);
        btnSignin.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAccSignup:
                openSignupActivity(); // This part does not work. Everything else works fine.
                break;

            case R.id.btnSignin:
                userSignin();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void openSignupActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the listener for `btnAccSignup`, you only added for `btnSignin`. Just add this:

```
btnAccSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
```